# Bootstrap v2.1.1 Modal Not getting fit correctly on mobile screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is the CSS part of the code:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1050;
  width: 560px;
  margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  *border: 1px solid #999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.modal-body {
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It works fine on my desktop, but when I try to shrink the size of the browser,
the modal window doesnt seem to introduce scroll bars correctly, and I don't
have any option to move vertically or horizontally.

Comment: You should create a jsFidde of this, it will be of great assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, the following idea came from [here](http://decadecity.net/blog/2013/03/25/modal-windows-for-small-screens-using-bootstrap-and-vertical-media-queries)

I'd edit the mobile CSS option as follows:

```
@media (max-width:480px){ .modal { position : absolute; top:10% } ... }
```